# How to solve carousel items out of div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I made a Bootstrap carousel the items are out of the div when I click on the prev or next buttons. My CSS global margin is set to 0 and when I remove the margin from the CSS it works.

Please, help me to solve the problem of keeping the margin 0 because I need it.

Here is a link to my issue https://codepen.io/zedblack2000/pen/rNLVYPV

HTML and CSS:

```css
*{
    padding: 0 !important ;
    margin: 0 !important;
    
}

body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
          <div class="container text-center my-3">

                <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide w-100" data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner w-100" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item row no-gutters active">
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/snapchat.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/facebook.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/viber.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/instagram.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/twitter.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/youtube.png"></div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item row no-gutters">

                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/google-plus.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/pinterest.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/reddit.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/tumblr.png"></div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/skype.png"> </div>
                            <div class="col-2 float-left"><img class="img-fluid" src="share/vimeo.png"> </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="control-top" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="control-top" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the properties margin and padding in the container :)

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;   
}
body{
  background-color:red;
}
.container{
  padding: 0 ;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*{
  padding: 0 ;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Try this